# Use the Microsoft Office theme and background in a WPF form

Tags: c#, wpf, office-interop

I'm developing an Outlook add-in that will be referencing a WPF project to display to the user.  Ideally, I'd like to make this WPF window share the same look and feel as Outlook.  Is there a way to determine the user's currently selected Office Background (Circuit, Clouds, etc.) and Office Theme (White, Light Gray, Dark Gray) and then apply that to my WPF window?

Comment: Please don't call a WPF `Window` a *"form"*. It is an insult to my beliefs and values.

Comment: Perhaps now that's it's been edited a response can be given that might help out?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [Microsoft Ribbon for WPF 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11877). That should get you started without buying third party controls.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I've been playing around with these controls some, but I'm not really finding a way to customize the theme or background of the ribbon itself, or a way to get the current Office theme and background and use that.  Is this a possibility?